# Optimize a function in R

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

I was looking since a long time for a programm code that optimize a parametric portfolio. 
 The investor’s problem is to choose the portfolio that maximizes his expected utility:[image: Expression]

Where `ri,t+1` is the return of stock `i`, `wi,t` is the weight of the stock `i`. A parametric portfolio is a portfolio whose weights depend on state variables, so:

[image: Expression]

Where `wi,t (bar)` is the weight of stock i on a benchmark portfolio, `teta` is the vector of coefficients to be estimated and `xi,t` is state variables.
So the coefficients that maximizes the investor’s utility are:

[image: Expression]

Recently, I received the following code, it presents the function to optimize:

```
func<-function(x,wb,nt, ret, A, B, C){ #A, B and C are the state variables,ret= the matrix of returns, wb and nt are from the optimization formula in equation 2. 
    wi=as.matrix(wb+(nt)*((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B)+(x[3]*C))) #wi is the weights (linear combinaison of asset variables A, B and C)
    wret=rowSums(wi*ret,na.rm=T) 
      ut=((1+wret)^(1-rr))/(1-rr) #utility function
      ######ut=log1p(wret) ##### to rr=1
      u=-mean(ut)
      pen=abs(sum((abs(wi)>0.2)*wi,na.rm=T))
    return(u+pen) 
    }
```

the problem is that I don't know how to use `optim` function in R to optimize the utility function. 
Could you please tell me what to write in the `optim` function in R. Honestly, I don't know how to write this code

```
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
      method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
                 "Brent"),
      lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

I know that `fn` is the `func`.
Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'ignore', "don't know"?

Comment: If it's a programming issue I think you'll get better help at StackOverflow. I also don't believe this to be on topic here.

Comment: hi, can you define your x, wb, nt, ret, A, B, C? If some of your variables in the optimization problem are discrete variables, i am not sure if optim will work. Your obj func appears to be non-linear.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: is there any constraint on the weight ?

Comment: Sum of weights is equal to 1